# Where does the TableDefinition.string method come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The code following is presented as an example in [Ruby on Rails 4.2.3](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html)

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.integer :shop_id, :creator_id
  t.string  :item_number, index: true
  # ^^^^^^
  t.string  :name, :value, default: "Untitled"
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Is this `.string` a method or something else? Which class or module does it come from? I've gone through the source code of `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition` on github, but nothing interesting could be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are shorthand for the [column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) method. The line you highlighted in longer-form could also be represented as follows:

```
t.column :name, :string
```

They're somewhat dynamically generated (from a hard-coded list) in the [schema_definitions](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L150) file.